# I am trying to scroll down a new tab in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to scroll down a new tab in selenium c#.

A new tab was created by clicking on the content while crawling.

I want to scroll in a new tab.

I tried

```
 this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(this.driver.WindowHandles[1]);
 this.runScript("window.scrollBy(0,100);");
```

and

```
 this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(this.driver.WindowHandles[1]);
 IWebElement tempElement = this.driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
 tempElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
```

and

```
 this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(this.driver.WindowHandles[1]);
 IWebElement tempElement = this.driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
 tempElement.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.PageDown);
```

and

```
new Actions(this.driver).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.PageDown).Perform();
```

I want to scroll in a new tab.